# Select the min or max date based on another column in sql

Tags: sql-server, date, datediff

I have the following data set:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #df

CREATE TABLE #df 
(
    PTID VARCHAR(10),
    HospitalID VARCHAR(5),
    Procedure_Dt date,
    Check_In_Dt DATE,
);

INSERT INTO #df (PTID, HospitalID, Procedure_Dt, Check_In_Dt)
VALUES
('X0001', 'WY', '2021-07-25', '2021-07-23'),
('X0001', 'WY', '2021-07-25', '2021-10-24'),
('X0001', 'WY', '2021-07-25', '2021-10-27'),
('X0001', 'WY', '2021-07-25', '2021-06-24'),
('X0001', 'WY', '2021-07-25', '2022-06-10'),
('X0002', 'CA', '2022-08-25', '2022-08-26'),
('X0002', 'CA', '2022-08-25', '2022-08-27'),
('X0002', 'CA', '2022-08-25', '2022-08-29'),
('X0002', 'CA', '2022-08-25', '2022-09-22'),
('X0003', 'AL', '2023-02-02', NULL)

--SELECT * FROM #df

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #df_datediff

;WITH CTE_datediff AS --Using only most recent quarter and year
(
    SELECT PTID
             , HospitalID
             , Procedure_Dt
             , Check_In_Dt
    FROM #df
)
SELECT DISTINCT a.PTID
             , HospitalID
             , Procedure_Dt
             , Check_In_Dt
     , DATEDIFF(dd, CAST(Check_In_Dt AS DATE), Procedure_Dt) AS Date_Diff
INTO #df_datediff
FROM CTE_datediff a
```

I would like to be able to select the `Check_In_Date` closest to the procedure date. However, this becomes complicated because some check in dates are after the procedure date and some are before.

Ultimately I would like the final dataset below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #df_final

CREATE TABLE #df_final 
(
    PTID VARCHAR(10),
    HospitalID VARCHAR(5),
    Procedure_Dt date,
    Check_In_Dt DATE,
    Date_Diff smallint
);

INSERT INTO #df_final (PTID, HospitalID, Procedure_Dt, Check_In_Dt, Date_Diff)
VALUES
('X0001', 'WY', '2021-07-25', '2021-07-23', 2),
('X0002', 'CA', '2022-08-25', '2022-08-26', -1)
('X0003', 'AL', '2023-02-02', NULL, NULL)
```

I attempted to do this by writing the following code:

```
SELECT a.PTID, HospitalID
             , Procedure_Dt
             , Check_In_Dt
             , a.Date_Diff
FROM #df_datediff a
    JOIN (SELECT PTID, MIN(Check_In_Dt) AS Check_In_Date FROM #df_datediff GROUP BY PTID) B
        ON a.PTID = B.PTID
           AND a.Check_In_Dt = B.Check_In_Date
UNION /*Since using MAX in the above query removes Null Facesheets, we use this union to include the null facesheet accesses*/
SELECT a.PTID, HospitalID
             , Procedure_Dt
             , Check_In_Dt
             , a.Date_Diff
FROM #df_datediff a
WHERE Check_In_Dt IS NULL;
```

The problem is, this selects, for PTID X0001, the check in date of '2021-06-24' while, for PTID X0002, it selects correct min negative value of '2022-08-26'. For X0001 it should be selecting '2021-07-23'

My goal is to keep the check in dates that are 0-40 days before a procedure as the numerator. All other check in dates should no be considered in the numerator.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Your final dataset has 2021-10-24, why is it not 2021-07-23 which is much closer?

Comment: Hi @Stu, i made a mistake in the above question regarding my desired dataset and have corrected it. The goal in the end is to sum all the check ins that are between 0-30 days before the procedure in the numerator and all other checks in would not be part of the numerator.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by numerator.

Comment: With the null technique your really just want to check for null as a possible match/max date. (`or chk_in is null and min_chk_in is null`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much a top-n-per-group type query, try the following:

```
select Ptid, HospitalId, Procedure_Dt, Check_In_Dt, Date_Diff
from (
  select *, 
    DateDiff(day, Check_In_Dt, Procedure_Dt) Date_Diff,
    Row_Number() 
      over(partition by ptid, HospitalId 
               order by Abs(DateDiff(day, Procedure_Dt, Check_In_Dt))
      ) rn
  from #df
)t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: This works great. I am assuming that I will still have to union the patient record that does not have a check in date?

Comment: Sorry I missed you still wanted the last row in there and the date_diff too, edited above.

Comment: I don't think you actually want to partition on hospital.